# How to catch `.param` callback's errors in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

In my app I want to validate some parameter of some route. Then, if it is not valid, I want to catch error from `next(err)` and convert it to some protocol format. Look at the code:

```
app = express();

router = express.Router();

router.param("id", function(req, res, next, id) {
  // something went wrong and we are:
  next(new Error("Bad ID"));
});

router.get("/some/route/to/:id", function(...) {...});

router.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  // here I want to get the "Bad ID" error,
  // but instead, this middleware is not invoked
});

app.use(router);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // and this middleware finally catches "Bad ID" error..
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2483) for this.

Answer (score 0):

didn't try to run it but it looks correct...

Try the following: `app.param` instead of `router.param` or `router.use(error middleware)` instead of `app.use(...)`

Comment: Im using `router.param` and `router.use`, *then*, `app.use`. And in the stack, `router.use` didn't catch the error, but `app.use` did.. =(